# Using a role per group and assign a host twice to a group

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ansible, ansible-inventory

In my environment I have multiple similar hosts and a playbook that uses groups to group roles like icinga, wordpress, gitlab, nginx, generic-php, java, etc. Every role is actually a docker-compose environment which is roles out in a specific location on the server like `/srv/docker/<service>/docker-compose.yml`. This path is described inside the role.

This services could have multiple instances, one or more per client. Because I don't care about the location (which server to use), it is possible, that a host whould be assigned with a role twice. There could be f.e. the role "wordpress" multiple times. Maybe Wordpress is a bad example, but take generic-php, which hold a HTTP service and executes the index.php in it.

Because the services are roles in Ansible and per role there is a group, like:

```
- name: Install ReverseProxies
  hosts: reverseproxies
  roles:
    - docker_reverseproxy
```

An when I have a look into the inventory.yaml like

```
    reverseproxies:
      hosts:
        server1:
        server2:
```

So I have a problem. How could I assign the group twice to a role. I know about assign a role twice to a host or group, but how would I assign a group twice to a host and define the "differences" like customerId or so? What do I miss? What would be best practice here?

Ideal would be something like this in the inventory (later as JSON in dynamic inventory)

```
    reverseproxies:
      hosts:
        server1:
          customerId: 1
        server1:
          customerId: 2
        server2:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be: change the roles that they verify some host specific variables. So this would be an example playbook:

```
...
    myservice:
      hosts:
        server1:
          service_data:
            customer1:
              port: 1080
            customer2:
              port: 1081
        server2:
          service_data:
            customer3:
              port: 1080
...
```

And inside the role iterate over the `service_data` var

```
- name: Configure Service instances
  include_tasks: manage_service.yml
  loop: "{{ service_data | default({}) | dict2items }}"
  tags:
    - docker
    - service
```

The included tasks then work with `item` or you could rename it with `loop_control` and `loop_var`.

```
- name: Define location
  set_fact:
    instance: "{{ item }}"
    service_path: "{{ service.base_dir }}/{{ item.key }}"
  tags:
    - docker
    - service

- name: Create "service" directory
  file:
    path: "{{ service_path }}"
    state: directory
  tags:
    - docker
    - service

- name: Copy "service" docker-compose folder
  template: src={{template.src}} dest={{template.dest}} owner={{template.owner}} group={{template.group}} mode={{template.mode}}
  with_items:
    - { src: "docker-compose.yml.j2", dest: "{{ service_path }}/docker-compose.yml", owner: 'root', group: 'root', mode: '0640' }
  loop_control:
    loop_var: template
  tags:
    - docker
    - service
....
```

The role should now create directories and so on per customerId list and this should generate unique docker-compose paths with unique and separated environments:

```
/srv/docker/service/customer1/docker-compose.yml
/srv/docker/service/customer2/docker-compose.yml
/srv/docker/<service>/<customerId>/docker-compose.yml
...
```